# How to get TouchesBegan working on a subView (Child view) rather than on Parent view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, touch-event

I have a setup like this

> Scroll View (Main View) -> CanvasView (SubView) -> Pages (SubView of
>   Canvas).

I want to add Touches began functionality to Pages , but for it to be detected I had to `setUserInteractionEnabled = YES;` to every parent view.

Now when I try to look for the view which is being detected I get the view of class UIScrollView.

As you can see in the image I have an UISCrollview on which a black screen whose subview is the white view. I need to do the touches began on the white view.

[image]

Comment: For this kind of thing, I would add separate UIPanGestures to each of the subviews and notify the ViewController or some kind of controller.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit ?

Comment: Can you please clarify what  do you mean by *"view which is being detected"* (how you detecting, and what do you expect to detect). If you overriding touchBegan of page view, and it triggered it definitely mean that Page had been touched.